# Java program won't run as application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just getting started with Java and Eclipse and I ran across a problem. I copied a program as part of a YouTube class to create a checkerboard. It runs as an applet but not as an application. When I try to run as an application I get:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Clay\GCMDLN.DLL: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at acm.program.DOSCommandLine.getCommandLine(Program.java:2268)
    at acm.program.Program.getCommandLine(Program.java:1477)
    at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:1207)`

Below is the code:

```
/* File CheckerBoard.java
 * ----------------------
 * This program creates a checkerboard
 */

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

/* This class draws a checkerboard on the graphics window. 
 * The size of the checkerboard is determined by the
 * constants NROWS and NCOLUMNS, and the checkerboard fills
 * the verticle space available.
 */

public class CheckerBoard extends GraphicsProgram {
    /* Number of rows */
    private static final int NROWS = 8;

    /* Number of columns */
    private static final int NCOLUMNS = 8;


    /* Runs the program */
    public void run() {
        int sqSize = getHeight() / NROWS;
        for (int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NCOLUMNS; j++) 
                        {
                int x = j * sqSize;
                int y = i * sqSize;
                GRect sq = new GRect (x, y, sqSize, sqSize);
                sq.setFilled(((i + j) % 2) != 0);
                add (sq);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets have different lifecycle methods, that is - they do not start by an invocation of a main(), and so you won't be able to run it through an IDE, at least not just by clicking run.

In Eclipse, right click your project, try Run Configurations > Run as Applet.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit processor.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Clay\GCMDLN.DLL: 
    Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
```

Looking at the error, your JVM is 64-bit but the `DLL GCMDLN.DLL` is buit for `32-bit` processor. you can either,

- Get a 64-bit `GCMDLN.DLL`, or
- Install and use 32-bit JVM with your GCMDLN.DLL